# how to use array.count in swift for-in loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, fatal-error

I'm a beginner in swift (probably) and I am learning how to use arrays I was trying to make a for-in loop with a loop amount of 1...array.count, but instead I get an error of:

> Fatal error: Index out of range Current stack trace: 0
> libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f0f71f0aea0
> swift_reportError + 50 1    libswiftCore.so
> 0x00007f0f71f7c0c0 *swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 69 2
>
> libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f0f71e775d7  +
> 3347927 3    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f0f71c94d80
> *fatalErrorMessage(*:*:file:line:flags:) + 19 4    libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.so       0x00007f0f755c7ad0 specialized
> Array.subscript.getter + 85 6    swift
> 0x00000000004f23c9  + 992201 7    swift
> 0x00000000004f6a40  + 1010240 8    swift
> 0x00000000004e62ef  + 942831 9    swift
> 0x00000000004d5093  + 872595 10   swift
> 0x00000000004d0e4e  + 855630 11   swift
> 0x0000000000473c16  + 474134 12   libc.so.6
> 0x00007f0f73771ab0 __libc_start_main + 231 13   swift
> 0x000000000047387a  + 473210 Stack dump:
> 0.    Program arguments: /usr/bin/swift -frontend -interpret Forecast.swift -disable-objc-interop -module-name Forecast
> /usr/bin/swift[0x4521834] /usr/bin/swift[0x451f48e]
> /usr/bin/swift[0x4521c48]
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x128a0)[0x7f0f7532b8a0]
> /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so(+0x3315d7)[0x7f0f71e775d7]
> /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so($ss18_fatalErrorMessage__4file4line5flagss5NeverOs12StaticStringV_A2HSus6UInt32VtF+0x13)[0x7f0f71c94d93]
> /usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.so($sSayxSicigSi_Tg5+0x55)[0x7f0f755c7b25]
> [0x7f0f7575d315] /usr/bin/swift[0x4f23c9] /usr/bin/swift[0x4f6a40]
> /usr/bin/swift[0x4e62ef] /usr/bin/swift[0x4d5093]
> /usr/bin/swift[0x4d0e4e] /usr/bin/swift[0x473c16]
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7f0f73771b97]
> /usr/bin/swift[0x47387a]

what do I do? Here is my code, it is for CodeAcademy:

```
var temperature: [Int] = [66, 68, 72, 76, 80, 82, 85, 85, 84, 82, 81, 78, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 65, 63, 62, 61, 63]

// Write your code below 
for i in 1...temperature.count{
  print(temperature[i])
}
```

Comment: Start by sharing your code :)

Comment: I added my code to the question

Answer (score 1):

I presume your goal is to print all the `temperature` elements. Change

```
for i in 1...temperature.count {
```

To

```
for i in 0..<temperature.count {
```

Array indexes start at zero and end at *one less* than the count. The `..<` operator handles this nicely. Or, even better, say

```
for i in temperature.indices {
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried temperature.indices and now I get the output of
66
68
72
76
80
82
85
85
84
82
81
78
74
73
72
71
70
69
68
65
63
62
61
63

Comment: @TechZacharyZN You should always use the collection indices. You will understand why it is so important when iterating a slice of the collection

Answer (score 1):

One more option is to use `forEach`:

`array.forEach { print($0) }`

Answer (score 1):

use `for i in temperature`. this is basic array iteration, keep in mind :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var temperature: [Int] = [66, 68, 72, 76, 80, 82, 85, 85, 84, 82, 81, 78, 74, 73, 72, 71, 70, 69, 68, 65, 63, 62, 61, 63]

// Write your code below 
for i in 1...temperature.count{
  print(temperature[i-1])
}
```

You are getting this error because `temperature[temperature.count]` doesn't exist. You need to limit it till `temperature[temperature.count-1]` and the index should start from 1 instead of 0.

Alternatively

```
for i in 0...(temperature.count-1){
  print(temperature[i])
}
```

Comment: What if the "temperature.count" is zero, the app will crash